# How to keep Google Maps sounds in Phone, while calls in Car Sound system, while driving?

Tags: audio, google-maps, google-maps-navigation

I am driving with Google Maps, while Bluetooth on. I cannot hear any Google Maps sounds if Bluetooth is on, my car stereo system is not playing them, while listening radio (I know you could change the input source but I do not want that).
So I turn Bluetooth off because then the sounds of Google Maps come from the phone.

How can you force all sounds from Google Maps to come from the phone, although you have Bluetooth on and connected to car stereo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the application *Waze* which has the setting *Play sound to phone speaker*, which solves the case, at least for now: all sounds of the applications go the phone speakers, while calls etc go to the car speakers.
I could not do that on Google Maps.

Answer (score 1):

Current version of Google Maps (10.47.1) seems to support this function:

1. tap on your avatar icon
2. tap on "Settings"
3. Scroll down and tap on "Navigation Settings"
4. Disable "play voice over Bluetooth

Tested with Bosch Infotainment headunit in Suzuki car and it worked exactly as expected.